# Running Parallel Tests using SpecRun+ LeanFT and Selenium C# in One

Tags: selenium, specflow, leanft

I have reviewed the link below, specifically in the section titled 'LeanFT-Selenium in One.'

https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Quality-and-Testing-Blog/Selenium-and-LeanFT-Easily-integrating-LeanFT-into-your-Selenium/ba-p/246519#.WmiSDqinGUk

[image]

Basically the LeanFT browser attaches to an instance of the browser launched by Selenium. In my case Chrome. The caveat from what I can tell is that there can only be one browser launched by Selenium at the time when LeanFT wants to attach itself to a browser instance. That means if I have two tests I want to run in parallel using Chrome, it would not work because that browser instance would need to be unique at the time when LeanFT attaches to a browser launched by selenium.  How can I acheive parallel test execution? Also, by the way I am using Specflow+SpecRun to bind gherkin to selenium/leanft automation code and it is my main test runner.

Even with the line of code where LeanFT attaches to Chromedriver (chrome browser) instance? It sounds like when that happens even increasing the threads in specflow's default.srprofile may have conflict because it seems you cannot have 2 chromedrivers running the LeanFT extension open when leanFT attaches to it.  I have not tried it, but curious what you experts think.  I am referring to the link I posted above. I attached a screen shot for the line of code I am referring to. How does Specflow handle situations like this with LeanFT

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this: *there can only be one browser launched by Selenium at the time when LeanFT wants to attach itself to a browser instance*. You can attach as many times as you want to a single browser

Answer (score 0):

Look in your default.srprofile file. It should look something like this:

```
  <Execution stopAfterFailures="500" retryFor ="None" testThreadCount="4" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
```

This will get you 4 threads.

Comment: Even with the line of code where LeanFT attaches to Chromedriver (chrome browser) instance? It sounds like when that happens even increasing the threads may have conflict because it seems you cannot have 2 chromedrivers running the LeanFT extension open when leanFT attaches to it. I am referring to the link I posted above. I attached a screen shot for the line of code I am referring to. How does Specflow handle situations like this with LeanFT

Comment: Did you try it? I have not used LeanFT but since that code drives the parallel process for every other browser in Specflow, I was hoping this would be the same,

Comment: Your suggestions did not work for me.  I tried to run two browser based tests for chrome, and they executed one by one